# How do I create a script that will take user input and use it in a terminal command using python 3.6?

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, linux-kernel, python-3.6

I'm trying to write a script in python3.6 on linux that takes a user's input (in the form of a URL), then performs the 'whois' terminal command on the input provided. I'm trying to launch it from IDLE. The best I've got is:

```
import os
os.system("clear")
os.system("gnome-terminal -e 'bash -c \'")
w = ""
w = (input("Who is your target?" ))
os.system("whois " + w)
```

It seems that after taking the input, the gnome terminal doesn't open, and nothing happens. I'm not very experienced in python at the moment and I'm struggling quite a bit with this!

Comment: What you mean by this - "whois on the input provided".

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear, I'd like to take the input the user enters (in the form of a url) and then use the terminal command "whois" to display information about the site, with all of this being completed in a single script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified your code a bit:

```
import os
os.system("clear")
w = ""
w = (input("Who is your target? "))
os.system("whois "+w)
```

Here is the demo:

[image: demo]

Comment: Thanks for that mate, it works when I launch it from a terminal window :) much appreciated. I am having a bit of difficulty launching it from IDLE, could that be potentially the issue with the new terminal window opening up?